# Xcode: Add text to label from textfield

Tags: xcode

Im working on my first iPhone application, and i would like to add text to a label from a textfield by clicking a button. The thing is that when i press the button the label gets the same value as the textfield.

Textfield value = blabla -> Label value = blabla

The thing i want is if i change the textfields value to "bla" and press the button again i want the labels value to become "blablabla". I want it to **ADD** text to the label **not to change** to the same as the textfield.

```
-(IBAction)ord1 {
label.text = textField1.text;      <-- Have to change this line?
[textField1 resignFirstResponder];

}
```

How do i do that :D?

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you're trying to do? Concat the text field to the label's text?

`label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", label.text, textField1.text];`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *labelstr = @"Your text for a label";
urlabelname.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",textfieldname.text,labelstr];
```